# Programmatically set a Binding to a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm writing a mockup to refactor and existing application and I've some issue setting a WPF Binding in code behind... the context is I've a RadPane (from Telerik suite, RadDocking control) and I want to set an header template. Right now I'm using this approach but when I dock-out a pane I got the header as System. instead of the content I got "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel"

[image]

Here's my existing code

```
var pane = new RadDocumentPane();
var view = CreateViewContent(viewModel);

 pane.DataContext = ((IView)view).DataContext;
       
 pane.Content = view;

 var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["Default"];

 var x = (StackPanel) dataTemplate.LoadContent();

 x.DataContext = ((IView)view).DataContext;

 pane.Header=x;
 pane.Title=x;
```

I tought of something as

```
 Binding binding = new Binding("?????");

 BindingOperations.SetBinding(pane, HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplateProperty, binding);
```

but I don't know how to tell the binding that I want to refer to the `dataTemplate`

## UPDATE 1

The reason I have to create a DataTemplate is that I've to add some context menu functionality as defined here

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Default">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title,Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" Margin="3,0,0,0" >
        <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            <telerik:RadContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Chiudi questo">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCommand, Source={StaticResource PaneCommands}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Chiudi tutti">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseAllCommand, Source={StaticResource PaneCommands}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Chiudi tutti tranne questo">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseAllExceptThisCommand, Source={StaticResource PaneCommands}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            </telerik:RadContextMenu>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand, Source={StaticResource PaneCommands}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>


    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your header template is doing, or what the DataContext of `view` has to do with it, but I think you want to just set the header template: `pane.HeaderTemplate = dataTemplate;`. Then, maybe, `pane.Header = ((IView)view).DataContext;` -- but if I knew what you're trying to put in the header, and what the datatemplate is trying to do with it, I could be more certain.

Comment: That worked, btw why have I to set the `Header`property as well?

Comment: `HeaderTemplate` tells the control how you want the value of `Header` to be displayed. You could try it without a `HeaderTemplate` and see what you get. But `Header` could be anything -- a control, a string, an integer (in which cases no template may be needed), or a viewmodel, in which case you'll probably want a template.

Comment: But I set the `DataContext` to `((IView)view).DataContext`; and the `dataTemplate` is defined inside a class that's different from the `DataContext`

Comment: It doesn't matter where the data template is defined. It matters what's in it. I don't understand what you're saying at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header template tells the control how you want to display the object you gave it for `Header`. If `Header` is just a string and you just want it displayed as ordinary UI text, you don't need to bother with a template. Likewise if `Header` is a control. But if you went to the trouble of writing a header `DataTemplate`, I imagine you had a reason for doing that.

So just give it the template:

```
pane.HeaderTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

Now, I have no idea what your template is doing or why you wrote one, or what's in the view's `DataContext` (should be a viewmodel, but in practice it could be literally anything).

But my guess is its something that you want to use as the `DataContext` of your header template, and that's exactly what it should be. If that's the case, you  want to set the actual header content like this:

```
pane.Header = ((IView)view).DataContext;
```

...that is, unless `((IView)view).DataContext` is likely to change at runtime. That can happen, and that's what bindings are for. Then you'd do this.

```
pane.SetBinding(
    HeaderedContentControl.HeaderProperty,
    new Binding("DataContext") { Source = view });
```

Looking at [the documentation for `RadDocumentPane`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/properties_t_telerik_windows_controls_raddocumentpane.htm), it has `TopTemplate` and `TitleTemplate` properties, and they don't mention `HeaderTemplate`. Lot going on there. But it seems to work like this.